# Zurb email template columns widths are being split evenly

Tags: html, zurb-foundation, inky

I'm using Zurb with inky (their email template language) and sass.  Following [their guide](https://foundation.zurb.com/emails/docs/grid.html) I have a very simple column setup I'm trying to achieve, three full-width columns stacked on top eachother.  The problem is, even with `small="12"` applied to all of them, they just take up even spacing.

```
<container>
  <row>
    <columns small="12"> test column 1 </columns>
    <columns small="12"> test column 2 </columns>
    <columns small="12"> test column 3 </columns>
  </row>
</container>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you have the right idea, unfortunately columns and rows don't work quite the way you're thinking -- you simply **can't** have more than 12 columns. When you specify a combined width greater than 12, the row will attempt to automatically scale the columns to a total of 12. Essentially, having three columns with `small="12"` is no different than having three columns with `small="4"`.

To achieve what you're looking for, you simply need to add three **rows** instead:

```
<container>
  <row>
    <columns small="12">test column 1</columns>
  </row>
  <row>
    <columns small="12">test column 2</columns>
  </row>
  <row>
    <columns small="12">test column 3</columns>
  </row>
</container>
```

Hope this helps! :)